# How can I memoize a function with lists as parameters or return values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, memoization

I am implementing a function with the following signature to solve the 0-1 knapsack problem in Haskell.

```
knapsack :: [Item] -> Capacity -> [Item]
```

Where the `Item` and `Capacity` files are defined as:

```
type Value = Int
type Weight = Int

type Capacity = Int

type Item = (Value, Weight)
```

I'd like to memoize it to have better performances. I tried to use [Data.MemoCombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-memocombinators/0.4.3/doc/html/Data-MemoCombinators.html) but I can't get how to have it work.

Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Can you post your `Item` and `Capacity` types? This is necessary to define a memoization function for them.

Comment: Sure, I just edited my question. They're simply an pair of integers and an integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I successfully used [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) for tasks like this. Each type that you want to use as a memoization index must implement [`HasTrie`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MemoTrie/0.6.1/doc/html/Data-MemoTrie.html#t%3aHasTrie). In your case, you don't have to imlement anything, because the package already provides instances for the primitive data types as well as for pairs and lists.

```
import Data.MemoTrie

type Value = Int
type Weight = Int

type Capacity = Int

type Item = (Value, Weight)

knapsack :: [Item] -> Capacity -> [Item]
knapsack = memo2 knapsack'
  where
    knapsack' items capacity = ... -- your computation goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for performance optimization for operations on lists, I'd suggest to take a look at the strict iteration functions, for example `Data.List.foldl'`:

> foldl' :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a